# Moving image that was created by drawImage in canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

How just move image in canvas? There are no x\y coordinates which I can change by += or -=.

Comment: How are you getting the image onto the canvas in the first place? You should have to specify the x/y offset in drawImage. Just change that.

Comment: I created image by drawImage(my_image, x, y), where x and y are coordinates of mouse click event.

Comment: There you go, just save those x and y values, increment them, then redraw.

Comment: And what about old image? Should I remove it every redraw cycle? Is it good for performance?

Comment: Canvas works like a traditional screen interface. To change "frames" you need to clear it and redraw. Performance depends on the client computer, the size of the canvas, and the size of the image you are redrawing. (if you want a more accurate measurement you'd need to do field tests)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canvas is an immedate drawing surface. When you make a call like `drawImage` the canvas renders the bitmap to the context and then forgets that anything ever happened. It keeps track of nothing.

That means you need to keep track of everything. If you want the image you move, you need to clear the canvas and redraw the image (and everything else in the scene) at a different location than before.

This comes up a lot in various ways so I made a tutorial on [managing the state of drawn objects and canvas interactivity](https://simonsarris.com/making-html5-canvas-useful/) that serves as a decent introduction to this topic. The tutorial uses rectangles that you can drag around the screen, but using images is nearly identical.