# ASP.NET Canvas Interacting Moving Objects

Tags: asp.net, canvas, web, html, drawimage

I am writing a webpage right now and I am stuck with a problem.

I want bubbles to move in a canvas and interact. Bubbles I draw with `canvas.DrawImage`. 
I dont know how to move the image to the right.

I tried `canvas.DrawImage(MyImageID,x,y)` and every iteration 
of `requestAnimationFrame i do x+=2`. It moves but leaves a train after it and I don't know, how I can make a direction of movement after interaction with another bubble with it.

How to make interaction between images I cannot even imagine.

So:
1)How to move an image in the canvas?
2)How to make interaction between images in a canvas(image is a circle bubble)?

Can you help me with it please?

Comment: Try this fiddle this might help you http://jsfiddle.net/XQpzU/4358/light/

Comment: That fiddle shows exactly the problem the OP is having.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving image that was created by drawImage in canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829429/moving-image-that-was-created-by-drawimage-in-canvas)